# Wireless notification when session start in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, kde, notification

When kde is charging appears a notifications this one disappears and appears again when my desktop is shown. It  says I am connected to a wireless net but this did not happen until I updated the system. This is annoying because the notification doesn't disappears by itself i must click it for that. I tried searching in notifications preferences but I cant find it. Does anyone know how to fix this?

---

[image: Snapshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this can be changed through System Settings -> Application and System Notifications -> Event Source: Notifies About Network Errors -> Active connection state changed. There, uncheck the "Show message in a popup".

Hope this helps. It is truly annoying that the notification doesn't disappear by itself, it would be quite harmless if it did.